# Can Metta improve one's luck?

Tags: personal-practice, metta-bhavana

Since one can benefit so much from practicing Metta, can it also helps improving one's luck?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For 2 reasons I can think of:

- Creates good Karma on which some can give results in this life time
- Makes you pleasant and likeable hence increasing chances of some one dealing with you and supporting you

Answer (score 0):

Luck is preparation meeting opportunity.

As discussed in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/8449/471), Metta makes one dearer to others, strengthens one's mental concentration, brings peace to one's mind, grants protection by the Devas (gods or angels) and provides protection from harm (e.g. fire, poison sword).

So, if you can have a better relationship with others, then this improves your social networks. If you have better mental concentration, then you can correctly identify opportunities that appear before you. If you have protection from harm, you may be led away from unfavourable situations.

Metta therefore, forms part of the right preparation that will allow you to seize the opportunities that come your way.

However, we should bear in mind that worldly luck is not permanent (anicca) and is part of the suffering (dukkha).

Comment: Thanks for ur response. How is it part of suffering? I'm not quite following.

Comment: Joy and sorrow, pleasure and pain, good luck and bad luck, gaining and losing loved ones, good health and wealth, life and death - all of these are not permanent. There will be ups and downs. And these go on forever. That's suffering.

Answer (score 0):

Sure... It might even expand your perception of "luck" so you can recognize the positive events that are always present but go ignored because we are the universe loving kindnessly bounded to ecah other through unconditional conditions...